# How to start procedure in oracle?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, stored-procedures, oracle-sqldeveloper

So I have this SELECT statement:

```
     SELECT emp.emp_name, pos_emp.POSITION_NAME
     from EMPLOYEE emp
     join POSITION_EMPLOYEE pos_emp
     on emp.POSITION_EMPLOYEE_POSITION_ID=pos_emp.POSITION_ID
     where emp.EMP_NAME='&employee_name';
```

When I enter employee name from keyboard it returns me his name(from EMPLOYEE table) and position(from POSITION_EMPLOYEE table). But I want to do this with stored procedure:

```
    create or replace PROCEDURE emp_pos(   EMPLOYEE_NAME IN EMPLOYEE.EMP_NAME%TYPE,
                                       POSITION_NAME OUT POSITION_EMPLOYEE.POSITION_NAME%TYPE )
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT pos_emp.POSITION_NAME
    INTO
        POSITION_NAME
    FROM EMPLOYEE emp
        JOIN
            POSITION_EMPLOYEE pos_emp
            ON
                emp.POSITION_EMPLOYEE_POSITION_ID 
                = pos_emp.POSITION_ID
    WHERE emp.EMP_NAME 
          = EMPLOYEE_NAME
    ;

END;
```

I am trying to start the procedure with begin:

```
begin emp_pos('&employee_name');
end;
```

The compiler gives me error:wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'EMP_POS'. Where am I wrong?

Comment: Use `begin emp_pos('&enter_name'); end;` just surround the parameter with quotes.

Comment: @krokodilko Still the same error.

Comment: Your procedure has 2 parameters, first IN, second OUT, so use: `DECLARE my_out_param VACHAR2(100);  BEGIN emp_pos('&enter_name', my_out_param); end;` I guess you want to print a result, if yes the append `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( my_out_param );` also to the BEGIN...END block.

Comment: @krokodilko thanks, that exports the positon. And how to export the name also.I tried to use emp.emp_name but it didn't work. DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( emp.emp_name || my_out_param ); Should I declare another variable? And how that varibale will store the employee with certain position?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SQL>set serveroutput on;
SQL>    create or replace PROCEDURE emp_pos(   EMPLOYEE_NAME IN EMPLOYEE.EMP_NAME%TYPE,
                                       POSITION_NAME OUT POSITION_EMPLOYEE.POSITION_NAME%TYPE )
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT pos_emp.POSITION_NAME
    INTO
        POSITION_NAME
    FROM EMPLOYEE emp
        JOIN
            POSITION_EMPLOYEE pos_emp
            ON
                emp.POSITION_EMPLOYEE_POSITION_ID 
                = pos_emp.POSITION_ID
    WHERE emp.EMP_NAME 
          = EMPLOYEE_NAME
    ;
  dbms_output.put_line(EMPLOYEE_NAME||'''s position is : '||POSITION_NAME);
END;
```

after defining this procedure, you may use in this way :

```
SQL>var v_emp_pos varchar2;
SQL>exec emp_pos('&employee_name',:v_emp_pos);
SQL>print v_emp_pos; -- just to print out this "out" parameter.
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Ho do you export the employee name too? I can't put EMPLOYEE_NAME in  dbms_output.put_line(' Your Position is : '||POSITION_NAME); When I start the function their is error:wrong number or types of arguments.

Comment: @Freak0345 excuse me , i didn't care the out parameter when calling. It's right now.

Comment: One more quiestion: What if I have one employee with two positons(more than one record). I know that doesn't make sense but... How to export all 
 records with his name and position. I tried with loop but it's not working:LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(EMPLOYEE_NAME||'''s position is : '||POSITION_NAME); END LOOP;

Comment: this is the error:exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows

Comment: @Freak0345 then you should examine your data for duplication (especially for employee_name)